# Hide TableColumns of TableView through CheckBox on separate Window

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml, tablecolumn

I have a window written in fxml with a TableView and a few TableColumns and other stuff.
I am trying to create a function in the controller to this window, that enables the user to select which columns to display via a set of checkboxes on a separate window.
This Window would be a child window of the HealthCheckTab. It would have a button that once pressed would get the state of all Checkboxes and would invoke a function in HealthcheckTab that updates the Tableview making the unwanted columns not visible.

This is the window with the TableView (Extract)

```
                        </TitledPane>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="classificationNumbers" animated="false"
                            text="HealthCheck Classification Numbers">
                            <content>
                                <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true"
                                    hbarPolicy="ALWAYS" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" pannable="true">
                                    <content>
                                        <TableView fx:id="HcTable" editable="true"
                                            maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                            minWidth="-Infinity" tableMenuButtonVisible="true">
                                            <columns>
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colId" editable="false"
                                                    maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="-1.0" text="ID" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colName" editable="false"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="60.0"
                                                    prefWidth="-1.0" text="Name" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colVal" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    minWidth="55.0" prefWidth="-1.0" text="Value" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colDescrCn" editable="false"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="90.0"
                                                    prefWidth="-1.0" text="Comment (CN)" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colDatatype" editable="false"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="80.0"
                                                    prefWidth="-1.0" text="Datatype" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colTool" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="-1.0" text="Tool" visible="false" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colPrio" editable="false"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="60.0"
                                                    prefWidth="-1.0" text="Priority" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colScope" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="-1.0" text="Scope" visible="false" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colAvg" editable="false"
                                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="50.0"
                                                    prefWidth="-1.0" text="AVG" visible="false" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colMin" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="-1.0" text="MIN" visible="false" />
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="colRelComp" prefWidth="122.0"
                                                    text="Relative Comparable" />
                                            </columns>
                                        </TableView>
                                    </content>
                                </ScrollPane>
                            </content>
                        </TitledPane>
```

This is the controller (Extract)

```
    @FXML
    private TreeView<String> HCTree;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Map> HcTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colId;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colVal;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colDescrCn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colDatatype;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colTool;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colPrio;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colScope;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colAvg;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colMin;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> colRelComp;



    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // REFRESH TABLE
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void refreshTable() {
        System.out.println("apply");
        colScope.setVisible(true);
        //colId.setVisible(false);
    

    }
```

Separate window (Extract)

```
@FXML
    private void handleApplyViewOptions() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("HealthCheckTab.fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
            HealthCheckTabController controller = loader.<HealthCheckTabController> getController();
            controller.refreshTable();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            java.lang.System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
        Stage stage = (Stage) btnApply.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
```

The refreshTable function does not hide the Scope Column at all.
I don't know why...

Comment: 1. The "scope" column appears to have index 7, not 8. (why not just call `colScope.setVisible(...)` anyway) 2. You're expecting that calling `setVisible(true)` will hide something? 3. Where are you calling `refreshTable()`? I recommend you create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem, and post that, instead of posting an incomplete part of your project (which has a lot of code that is not relevant to the problem).

Comment: yes I was expecting setVisible(true) to change something, what am I missing/doing wrong? I left out the unnecessary parts and added the lines where refresh is invoked...

Comment: Surely if you want to *hide* something you would use `setVisible(false)`????

Comment: In your `handleApplyViewOptions` method, I don't see where you ever show the new stage you create.

Comment: Again, all this would be so much easier to diagnose (either for you, or for others), if you would write a specific (i.e. new) application that just tried to do the part you are having trouble with. Simply posting snippets from a larger project is not much help.

Comment: in that case colScope is initialised as not visible: `<TableColumn fx:id="colScope" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                                    minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="-1.0" text="Scope" visible="false" />` and I would be expecting it to somehow appear...

Comment: OK, I see that now. It sort of contradicts the title of your question... :). Where are you showing the new stage you create in `handleApplyViewOptions()`? If you don't show the stage, you won't see the changes you made to it.

Comment: right, if I show the stage it opens a new Window with the correct view, I want to update the old one instead; this is my first fx-project, I am sorry if my question is trivial... How do I change this: `Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);` into the stage the input to open my Window that invokes the refresh function comes from?

Comment: I'm confused. If the view is already showing, why are you loading the FXML file again? Write a [MCVE] and post that, instead of the code you have posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading a new copy of the UI defined in `HealthCheckTab.fxml` and calling `refreshTable` on the controller for that UI (which is never displayed).

Probably an easier approach for this is to register an `onHidden` handler with the dialog you create, and call `refreshTable` when the dialog is hidden.

Here is a SSCCE:

Main.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<BorderPane fx:controller="MainController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
        <TableView >
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" text="Name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="optionalColumn" text="Data" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER">
            <Button text="Configure View" onAction="#showViewOptions" />
            <padding>
                <Insets top="5" left="5" bottom="5" right="5"/>
            </padding>
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

MainController.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Void, Void> nameColumn ;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Void, Void> optionalColumn ;

    @FXML
    private void showViewOptions() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ViewOptionsController.class.getResource("ViewOptions.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        ViewOptionsController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setOptionalColumnVisible(optionalColumn.isVisible());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initOwner(nameColumn.getTableView().getScene().getWindow());
        stage.setOnHidden(e -> {
            refreshTable(controller.isOptionalColumnVisible());
        });
        stage.show();
    }

    private void refreshTable(boolean showOptionalColumn) {
        optionalColumn.setVisible(showOptionalColumn);
    }
}
```

ViewOptions.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<VBox fx:controller="ViewOptionsController" spacing="5" alignment="center" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <CheckBox text="Show Data Column" fx:id="optionalColumnVisibleCheckBox" />
    <Button text="OK" onAction="#close" />
    <padding>
        <Insets top="5" left="5" right="5" bottom="5"/>
    </padding>
</VBox>
```

ViewOptionsController.java:

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;

public class ViewOptionsController {

    @FXML
    private CheckBox optionalColumnVisibleCheckBox ;

    public BooleanProperty optionalColumnVisibleProperty() {
        return optionalColumnVisibleCheckBox.selectedProperty();
    }

    public final boolean isOptionalColumnVisible() {
        return optionalColumnVisibleProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setOptionalColumnVisible(boolean optionalColumnVisible) {
        optionalColumnVisibleProperty().set(optionalColumnVisible);
    }

    @FXML
    private void close() {
        optionalColumnVisibleCheckBox.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

Application class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HideColumnsFromDialog extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(MainController.class.getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

As an aside, note that the functionality you are implementing here is built in to the table view already: you can use

```xml
<TableView fx:id="HcTable" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" ... >
```

and the table will show a button that shows a drop-down menu, from which the user can choose which columns are visible.